# Fetch next record within a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

```
EMP_ID     ,DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT,CITY       ,RANK
2258325    ,1/18/2020 5:37      ,London     ,1
2258325    ,1/19/2020 11:01     ,Manchester ,2
2258325    ,1/20/2020 15:06     ,London     ,3
2656700    ,1/20/2020 23:59     ,London     ,1
2656700    ,1/21/2020 6:48      ,Manchester ,2
2656700    ,1/21/2020 6:48      ,Liverpool  ,3
2656700    ,1/26/2020 10:47     ,London     ,4
6631583    ,1/18/2020 18:00     ,London     ,1
6631583    ,1/19/2020 14:25     ,Manchester ,2
6631583    ,1/20/2020 8:53      ,Liverpool  ,3
6631583    ,1/20/2020 14:48     ,Manchester ,4
6631583    ,1/21/2020 11:34     ,London     ,5
```

I want a query to get the employee who were in london and come back to london.
the firt location should be london second is the first location after london and third location should be london

I used the following query but it miss some employees

```
    select emp_id , date_of_movement as first_movement , city as first_city ,lead 
    (DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT, 1) over ( partition by emp_id order by DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT) as second_movement ,  
    lead (city , 1) over ( partition by emp_id order by DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT) as second_city ,
    lead (DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT, 2) over ( partition by emp_id order by DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT) as third_movement ,  
    lead (city , 1) over ( partition by emp_id order by DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT) as third_city ,
from table
```

result of the code

```
CUSTOMER_ID,first_movement ,first_city,second_movment ,second_movement,third_movment  ,third_city
2258325    ,1/18/2020 5:37 ,London    ,1/19/2020 11:01,Manchester     ,1/20/2020 15:06,London
2656700    ,1/20/2020 23:59,London    ,1/21/2020 6:48 ,Manchester     ,1/21/2020 6:48 ,Liverpool
6631583    ,1/18/2020 18:00,London    ,1/19/2020 14:25,Manchester     ,1/20/2020 8:53 ,Liverpool
```

This code catch the employee it their track of movement ( ex. emp_id : 2258325 )
1 - London 
2 - any other city
3 - London

It will not works fine If the movement of the employee like the following
1 - london 
2 - any other city
3 - any other city
4 - London

i want the result to be like

```
CUSTOMER_ID,first_movement ,first_city,second_movement,second_city,third_movement ,third_city
2258325    ,1/18/2020 5:37 ,London    ,1/19/2020 11:01,Manchester ,1/20/2020 15:06,London
2656700    ,1/20/2020 23:59,London    ,1/21/2020 6:48 ,Manchester ,1/26/2020 10:47,London
6631583    ,1/18/2020 18:00,London    ,1/19/2020 14:25,Manchester ,1/21/2020 11:34,London
```

Any suggestion please?

---

```
 WITH YOUR_TABLE (EMP_ID,
                 DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT,
                 CITY,
                 RANK_)
     AS (SELECT 2258325,
                '1/18/2020 5:37',
                'London',
                1
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2258325,
                '1/19/2020 11:01',
                'Manchester',
                2
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2258325,
                '1/20/2020 15:06',
                'London',
                3
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2656700,
                '1/20/2020 23:59',
                'London',
                1
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2656700,
                '1/21/2020 6:48',
                'Manchester',
                2
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2656700,
                '1/21/2020 6:48',
                'Liverpool',
                3
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2656700,
                '1/26/2020 10:47',
                'London',
                4
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6631583,
                '1/18/2020 18:00',
                'London',
                1
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6631583,
                '1/19/2020 14:25',
                'Manchester',
                2
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6631583,
                '1/20/2020 8:53',
                'Liverpool',
                3
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6631583,
                '1/20/2020 14:48',
                'Manchester',
                4
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6631583,
                '1/21/2020 11:34',
                'London',
                5
           FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
         SELECT 6631583,
                '1/22/2020 14:48',
                'Manchester',
                6
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6631583,
                '1/24/2020 11:34',
                'London',
                7
           FROM DUAL)   -- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE   SELECT EMP_ID,
         MAX (CASE WHEN MINRN = RANK_ THEN DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT END)
            AS first_movement,
         MAX (CASE WHEN MINRN = RANK_ THEN CITY END) AS first_CITY,
         MAX (CASE WHEN MINRN + 1 = RANK_ THEN DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT END)
            AS SECOND_movement,
         MAX (CASE WHEN MINRN + 1 = RANK_ THEN CITY END) AS SECOND_CITY,
         MAX (CASE WHEN MAXRN = RANK_ THEN DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT END)
            AS THIRD_movement,
         MAX (CASE WHEN MAXRN = RANK_ THEN CITY END) AS THIRD_CITY
    FROM (SELECT T.*,
                 MAX (CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN RANK_ END)
                    OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID)
                    AS MAXRN,
                 MIN (CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN RANK_ END)
                    OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID)
                    AS MINRN
            FROM YOUR_TABLE T)    WHERE MAXRN - MINRN > 1 GROUP BY EMP_ID;
```

check this it is not works @Tejash

result should be like this:

[image]

Comment: updated SQL below according to your updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emp_id, 
       Lead (datetime_of_movement, 0) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY emp_id 
           ORDER BY datetime_of_movement ASC)  AS first_movement, 
       Lead (city, 0) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY emp_id 
           ORDER BY datetime_of_movement ASC)  AS first_city, 
       Lead (datetime_of_movement, 1) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY emp_id 
           ORDER BY datetime_of_movement ASC) AS second_movement, 
       Lead (city, 1) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY emp_id 
           ORDER BY datetime_of_movement ASC) AS second_city, 
       Lead (datetime_of_movement, 0) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY emp_id 
           ORDER BY datetime_of_movement DESC) AS third_movement, 
       Lead (city, 0) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY emp_id 
           ORDER BY datetime_of_movement DESC) AS third_city, 
FROM   table 
WHERE frist_city = "London" AND third_city = "London"
```

I couldn't test this SQL but maybe helpful. please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I think you supposed in your code London is the last location but in my case it is not.

Comment: of course, you can change where clause or remove them. it just shows as example

Comment: I will try, I just wonder if the lead function can search for the next London record instead of point the next record using fixed number in the function.

Comment: Yep. then you need to add where clause to find the certain city.

Comment: I think this will be the best solution:) @Nawaf

Comment: Please check the link especially for the emp 6631583 it will not work
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9d7a4b5b974c139a5f55144f955c770

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below script. But this will return only onle row as only one EMP has city London where Rank = 3 ( and as per explanation your concern is location 3 as well)

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26f611b119fbda19e99db2c534a67a8e)

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT A.EMP_ID CUSTOMER_ID,
A.DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT first_movement ,A.city first_city,
B.DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT secondt_movement,B.city second_city,
C.DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT third_movement ,C.city third_city
FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN your_table B ON A.Rank = B.Rank - 1 AND A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID
INNER JOIN your_table C ON A.Rank = C.Rank - 2 AND A.EMP_ID = C.EMP_ID
WHERE A.RANK = 1
AND C.City = 'London'
```

New logic if the last city is not the third city-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f43cac10716a04ea19cdb874aa344c1)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A.EMP_ID,A.DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT,A.CITY,A.RANK, 
    CASE WHEN A.RANK > 2 THEN 3 ELSE A.Rank END NEW_RANK 
    FROM your_table A
    WHERE A.RANK IN (1,2)
    OR A.RANK = (SELECT MAX(Rank) FROM your_table B WHERE B.EMP_ID = A.EMP_ID)
)

SELECT 
A.EMP_ID CUSTOMER_ID,
A.DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT first_movement ,A.city first_city,
B.DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT secondt_movement,B.city second_city,
C.DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT third_movement ,C.city third_city
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.NEW_RANK = B.NEW_RANK - 1 AND A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID
INNER JOIN CTE C ON A.NEW_RANK = C.NEW_RANK - 2 AND A.EMP_ID = C.EMP_ID
WHERE A.NEW_RANK = 1
AND C.City = 'London'
```

Comment: he just references one table.

Comment: I also used one single table here. Whats wrong with it? @AlexandrBiship

Comment: this is my issue exactly some times London comes as forth or fifth record.

Comment: That can be addresses as well. But right now I am confused thinking why people feel happy to put down vote in posts with out any reason :(

Comment: Sorry for that also I got some down vote without any causes.

Comment: Hi @Nawaf, can you please check the newly added logic works for your or not.

Comment: Not work in some cases could you check the emp number 6631583 @mkRabbani  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9d7a4b5b974c139a5f55144f955c770

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a record starting from London then next record and the last London record. You can use the combination of the conditional aggregate and analytical function as following:

> ```
> SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE (
>   2      EMP_ID,
>   3      DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT,
>   4      CITY,
>   5      RANK
>   6  ) AS
>   7  (
>   8      SELECT 2258325    ,'1/18/2020 5:37'      ,'London'     ,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   9      SELECT 2258325    ,'1/19/2020 11:01'     ,'Manchester' ,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  10      SELECT 2258325    ,'1/20/2020 15:06'     ,'London'     ,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  11      SELECT 2656700    ,'1/20/2020 23:59'     ,'London'     ,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  12      SELECT 2656700    ,'1/21/2020 6:48'      ,'Manchester' ,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  13      SELECT 2656700    ,'1/21/2020 6:48'      ,'Liverpool'  ,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  14      SELECT 2656700    ,'1/26/2020 10:47'     ,'London'     ,4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  15      SELECT 6631583    ,'1/18/2020 18:00'     ,'London'     ,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  16      SELECT 6631583    ,'1/19/2020 14:25'     ,'Manchester' ,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  17      SELECT 6631583    ,'1/20/2020 8:53'      ,'Liverpool'  ,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  18      SELECT 6631583    ,'1/20/2020 14:48'     ,'Manchester' ,4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>  19      SELECT 6631583    ,'1/21/2020 11:34'     ,'London'     ,5 FROM DUAL
>  20  )
>  21  -- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
>  22  SELECT
>  23      EMP_ID,
>  24      MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN = RANK THEN DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT END) AS first_movement,
>  25      MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN = RANK THEN CITY END) AS first_CITY,
>  26      MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN + 1 = RANK THEN DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT END) AS SECOND_movement,
>  27      MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN + 1 = RANK THEN CITY END) AS SECOND_CITY,
>  28      MAX(CASE WHEN MAXRN = RANK THEN DATETIME_OF_MOVEMENT END) AS THIRD_movement,
>  29      MAX(CASE WHEN MAXRN = RANK THEN CITY END) AS THIRD_CITY
>  30  FROM
>  31      (
>  32          SELECT T.*,
>  33              MAX(CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN RANK END) OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_ID) AS MAXRN,
>  34              MIN(CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN RANK END) OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_ID) AS MINRN
>  35          FROM YOUR_TABLE T
>  36      )
>  37  WHERE MAXRN - MINRN > 1
>  38  GROUP BY EMP_ID;
>
>     EMP_ID FIRST_MOVEMENT  FIRST_CITY SECOND_MOVEMENT SECOND_CIT THIRD_MOVEMENT  THIRD_CITY
> ---------- --------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- --------------- ----------
>    2258325 1/18/2020 5:37  London     1/19/2020 11:01 Manchester 1/20/2020 15:06 London
>    2656700 1/20/2020 23:59 London     1/21/2020 6:48  Manchester 1/26/2020 10:47 London
>    6631583 1/18/2020 18:00 London     1/19/2020 14:25 Manchester 1/21/2020 11:34 London
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you, but i think in some complicated cases will not works.

Comment: check my comment the query will not work for the employee # 6631583